# INSERT from textbox to sql get question marks

Tags: asp.net, sql, textbox, hebrew

I have site in asp.net 4 and in hebrew language.

When the site was in my computer - everything works great...

After i've been uploaded the site to WINHOST servers,  when i enter value in hebrew on the text-box - the sql fields get question marks... like: ????

it's important to say that it's not my first website on WINHOST and they works great, this it's the first time that i see that problem.

what i can to do?

I've tried to add globalization to the web config with hebrew encoding.. but it's changed nothing.

Comment: How about the database? Make sure you set the collation correctly

Comment: Check the encoding during every step of the process, from user to server and from server to database, and in the database itself. It can't be ASCII at any time, otherwise languages like Hebrew won't work.

Comment: at the database the columns are on nvarchar ofcourse... i don't remember where i can to see the encoding in the database ?

Comment: i see : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 

but i search how to change it

Comment: OK i found the problem. i used version 2008, but on the server i made version 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was N' prefix before '" + bla_string + "'

like:  N'" + bla_string + "'

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely on your database. You should use `nchar`, `nvarchar` and `ntext` for all character data.